# ossec-agentd(4105): ERROR: No valid IP found

Tags: linux, centos

First time using ossec, test environment, config issue

I created a new server (centos 8, ossec 3.4).  On the server, I installed the ossec server.  The server appears to be able to properly monitor itself (I get emails when I restart ossec).  I'll call this the ossec server moving forward.

I installed the ossec agent on a different server (centos 7, ossec 3.4).  Ill call this the agent moving forward.

I used manage_agents on the ossec server to add the ossec agent.

```
****************************************
* OSSEC HIDS v3.4.0 Agent manager.     *
* The following options are available: *
****************************************
   (A)dd an agent (A).
   (E)xtract key for an agent (E).
   (L)ist already added agents (L).
   (R)emove an agent (R).
   (Q)uit.
Choose your action: A,E,L,R or Q: L

Available agents:
   ID: 228, Name: agen, IP: 192.168.1.228

** Press ENTER to return to the main menu.
```

I then extracted a key for the agent

```
****************************************
* OSSEC HIDS v3.4.0 Agent manager.     *
* The following options are available: *
****************************************
   (A)dd an agent (A).
   (E)xtract key for an agent (E).
   (L)ist already added agents (L).
   (R)emove an agent (R).
   (Q)uit.
Choose your action: A,E,L,R or Q: E

Available agents:
   ID: 228, Name: agen, IP: 192.168.1.228
Provide the ID of the agent to extract the key (or '\q' to quit): 228

Agent key information for '228' is:
MjI4IGxob3N0LWplbmtpbnMgMTkyLjE2OC4xLjIyOCA3MzMyYTZkNjcwNzg1YmUyNGY5MzdiZTQ2NWY2MmM2MDg3ZTg5MWE3YWU0NjlkMmU1YWIxNWZjMTY3NzAxMThj

** Press ENTER to return to the main menu.
```

I used manage_agent on the agent to try to import the key.

```
****************************************
* OSSEC HIDS v3.4.0 Agent manager.     *
* The following options are available: *
****************************************
   (I)mport key from the server (I).
   (Q)uit.
Choose your action: I or Q: I

* Provide the Key generated by the server.
* The best approach is to cut and paste it.
*** OBS: Do not include spaces or new lines.

Paste it here (or '\q' to quit): MjI4IGxob3N0LWplbmtpbnMgMTkyLjE2OC4xLjIyOCA3MzMyYTZkNjcwNzg1YmUyNGY5MzdiZTQ2NWY2MmM2MDg3ZTg5MWE3YWU0NjlkMmU1YWIxNWZjMTY3NzAxMThj

Agent information:
   ID:228
   Name:agen
   IP Address:192.168.1.228

Confirm adding it?(y/n): y
2019/10/22 13:26:09 manage_agents: ERROR: Cannot unlink /queue/rids/sender: No such file or directory
Added.
** Press ENTER to return to the main menu.
```

It throws an odd error, but claims the key is Added.  So, finally, I try to restart ossec on the agent, but I get a series of error that indicate my config is bad.

```
[root@agen bin]# /var/ossec/bin/ossec-client.sh restart
ossec-logcollector not running ..
ossec-syscheckd not running ..
ossec-agentd not running ..
Killing ossec-execd ..
OSSEC HIDS 3.4.0 Stopped
Starting OSSEC HIDS 3.4.0...
Started ossec-execd...
2019/10/22 13:27:35 ossec-agentd(4105): ERROR: No valid server IP found.
2019/10/22 13:27:35 ossec-agentd(1215): ERROR: No client configured. Exiting.
ossec-agentd did not start
```

Okay, so, I think I need to make a config change in ossec.conf, but I dont see anything in there that looks appropriate.

```
<ossec_config>
  <global>
    <email_notification>yes</email_notification>
    <email_to>REDACTED</email_to>
    <smtp_server>REDACTED</smtp_server>
    <email_from>REDACTED</email_from>
  </global>

  <rules>
    <include>rules_config.xml</include>
    <include>pam_rules.xml</include>
    <include>sshd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>telnetd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>syslog_rules.xml</include>
    <include>arpwatch_rules.xml</include>
    <include>symantec-av_rules.xml</include>
    <include>symantec-ws_rules.xml</include>
    <include>pix_rules.xml</include>
    <include>named_rules.xml</include>
    <include>smbd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>vsftpd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>pure-ftpd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>proftpd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>ms_ftpd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>ftpd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>hordeimp_rules.xml</include>
    <include>roundcube_rules.xml</include>
    <include>wordpress_rules.xml</include>
    <include>cimserver_rules.xml</include>
    <include>vpopmail_rules.xml</include>
    <include>vmpop3d_rules.xml</include>
    <include>courier_rules.xml</include>
    <include>web_rules.xml</include>
    <include>web_appsec_rules.xml</include>
    <include>apache_rules.xml</include>
    <include>nginx_rules.xml</include>
    <include>php_rules.xml</include>
    <include>mysql_rules.xml</include>
    <include>postgresql_rules.xml</include>
    <include>ids_rules.xml</include>
    <include>squid_rules.xml</include>
    <include>firewall_rules.xml</include>
    <include>apparmor_rules.xml</include>
    <include>cisco-ios_rules.xml</include>
    <include>netscreenfw_rules.xml</include>
    <include>sonicwall_rules.xml</include>
    <include>postfix_rules.xml</include>
    <include>sendmail_rules.xml</include>
    <include>imapd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>mailscanner_rules.xml</include>
    <include>dovecot_rules.xml</include>
    <include>ms-exchange_rules.xml</include>
    <include>racoon_rules.xml</include>
    <include>vpn_concentrator_rules.xml</include>
    <include>spamd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>msauth_rules.xml</include>
    <include>mcafee_av_rules.xml</include>
    <include>trend-osce_rules.xml</include>
    <include>ms-se_rules.xml</include>
    <!-- <include>policy_rules.xml</include> -->
    <include>zeus_rules.xml</include>
    <include>solaris_bsm_rules.xml</include>
    <include>vmware_rules.xml</include>
    <include>ms_dhcp_rules.xml</include>
    <include>asterisk_rules.xml</include>
    <include>ossec_rules.xml</include>
    <include>attack_rules.xml</include>
    <include>openbsd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>clam_av_rules.xml</include>
    <include>dropbear_rules.xml</include>
    <include>sysmon_rules.xml</include>
    <include>opensmtpd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>exim_rules.xml</include>
    <include>openbsd-dhcpd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>dnsmasq_rules.xml</include>
    <include>nsd_rules.xml</include>
    <include>local_rules.xml</include>
  </rules>


  <syscheck>
    <!-- Frequency that syscheck is executed - default to every 22 hours -->
    <frequency>79200</frequency>

    <!-- Directories to check  (perform all possible verifications) -->
    <directories check_all="yes">/etc,/usr/bin,/usr/sbin</directories>
    <directories check_all="yes">/bin,/sbin,/boot</directories>

    <!-- Files/directories to ignore -->
    <ignore>/etc/mtab</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/mnttab</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/hosts.deny</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/mail/statistics</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/random-seed</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/adjtime</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/httpd/logs</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/utmpx</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/wtmpx</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/cups/certs</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/dumpdates</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/svc/volatile</ignore>

    <!-- Windows files to ignore -->
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/System32/LogFiles</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/Debug</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/WindowsUpdate.log</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/iis6.log</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/system32/wbem/Logs</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/system32/wbem/Repository</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/Prefetch</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/PCHEALTH/HELPCTR/DataColl</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/SoftwareDistribution</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/Temp</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/system32/config</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/system32/spool</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/system32/CatRoot</ignore>
  </syscheck>


  <rootcheck>
    <rootkit_files>/var/ossec//etc/shared/rootkit_files.txt</rootkit_files>
    <rootkit_trojans>/var/ossec//etc/shared/rootkit_trojans.txt</rootkit_trojans>
    <system_audit>/var/ossec//etc/shared/system_audit_rcl.txt</system_audit>
    <system_audit>/var/ossec//etc/shared/cis_rhel_linux_rcl.txt</system_audit>
    <system_audit>/var/ossec//etc/shared/cis_rhel5_linux_rcl.txt</system_audit>
  </rootcheck>


  <global>
    <white_list>127.0.0.1</white_list>
    <white_list>^localhost.localdomain$</white_list>
    <white_list>192.168.1.10</white_list>
<white_list>192.168.1.228</white_list>
  </global>
  <remote>
    <connection>syslog</connection>
  </remote>
  <remote>
    <connection>secure</connection>
  </remote>
  <alerts>
    <log_alert_level>1</log_alert_level>
    <email_alert_level>7</email_alert_level>
  </alerts>

  <command>
    <name>host-deny</name>
    <executable>host-deny.sh</executable>
    <expect>srcip</expect>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>firewall-drop</name>
    <executable>firewall-drop.sh</executable>
    <expect>srcip</expect>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>disable-account</name>
    <executable>disable-account.sh</executable>
    <expect>user</expect>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>restart-ossec</name>
    <executable>restart-ossec.sh</executable>
    <expect></expect>
  </command>


  <command>
    <name>route-null</name>
    <executable>route-null.sh</executable>
    <expect>srcip</expect>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>


  <!-- Active Response Config -->
  <active-response>
    <!-- This response is going to execute the host-deny
       - command for every event that fires a rule with
       - level (severity) >= 6.
       - The IP is going to be blocked for  600 seconds.
      -->
    <command>host-deny</command>
    <location>local</location>
    <level>6</level>
    <timeout>600</timeout>
  </active-response>

  <active-response>
    <!-- Firewall Drop response. Block the IP for
       - 600 seconds on the firewall (iptables,
       - ipfilter, etc).
      -->
    <command>firewall-drop</command>
    <location>local</location>
    <level>6</level>
    <timeout>600</timeout>
  </active-response>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/messages</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/secure</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/maillog</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>apache</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/nginx/access.log</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>apache</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/nginx/error.log</location>
  </localfile>
</ossec_config>
```

My question, where or how do I make these configs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
cd /var/ossec/queue/rids/
cp 001 sender
```

I re-registered the agent

```
/var/ossec/bin/manage_agents
```

and it was solved and the process removes the **sender** file from the path `/var/ossec/queue/rids/`